# Cómo crear un programa python que pueda modificar otro programa python

Tags: python

Estoy buscando una forma de crear un programa para poder modificar mi programa de conversor de monedas. Este programa funciona de la siguiente manera:

```
def menu():

    x = int(input("Escoge tu moneda original, siendo:\n1.Dólares\n2.Euros\n3.Soles\n4.Reales\n5.Pesos uruguayos\n6.Pesos Chilenos\n")) #(eeuu,europa,peru,brasil,uruguay,chile)

    y = int(input("Escoge tu moneda convertida, siendo:\n1.Dólares\n2.Euros\n3.Soles\n4.Reales\n5.Pesos uruguayos\n6.Pesos Chilenos\n"))

    valorx = float(input("Cantidad a convertir: "))

    if x == 1:
        if y == 2:
            y = "euros"
            valory = valorx*0.89
        elif y == 3:
            y = "soles"
            valory = valorx*3.32
        elif y == 4:
            y = "reales"
            valory = valorx*3.92
        elif y == 5:
            y = "pesos uruguayos"
            valory = valorx*33.81
        elif y == 6:
            y = "pesos chilenos"
            valory = valorx*680.50

        print(valorx , "dólares equivalen a ", valory , y)

    if x == 2:
        if y == 1:
            y = "dólares"
            valory = valorx*1.12
        elif y == 3:
            y = "soles"
            valory = valorx*3.73
        elif y == 4:
            y = "reales"
            valory = valorx*4.41
        elif y == 5:
            y = "pesos uruguayos"
            valory = valorx*37.97
        elif y == 6:
            y = "pesos chilenos"
            valory = valorx*764.31

        print(valorx , "euros equivalen a ", valory ,y)
```

etc.. hasta llegar a `x == 6` como podrán imaginar.
Me gustaría poder crear un programa que pueda insertar nuevas opciones de moneda, con sus respectivos valores de conversión.

Comment: Bienvenido dubidu, según tu pregunta dice que quieres modificar un programa desde otro programa para ingresar nuevas opciones de moneda... No sería más conveniente trabajar con algún archivo que almacene esa información?? Podrías usar un archivo json para almacenar los datos y en el podrás insertar los nuevos... Y podrías leerlo desde cualquier otro programa

Comment: Es que deseo practicar con python:)

Comment: @dubidu el comentario de Victor es la opción correcta, es decir crea un json con las opciones, lees el valor de las conversiones, haces las operaciones segun esa data, y si quieres añadir mas conversiones editas con python el archivo json. Nunca se modifica un archivo python con otro script de python (salvo casos excepcionales pero este no es el caso)

Comment: Editar un archivo de python con otro archivo python te va complicar muchisimo, de verdad te recomendaría que trabajes con archivos .json, y no es nada complicado aprender como se trabaja con este tipo de archivos. Te dejo este enlace que explica como insertar nuevos registros a un archivo json por si es que estas interesado en el tema: https://www.analyticslane.com/2018/07/16/archivos-json-con-python/

Comment: muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tu quieres hacer es muy interesante y el tema se llama [metaprogramación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramaci%C3%B3n), y son técnicas avanzadas y demasiado poderosas.

El uso de la metaprogramación va más allá de un conversor como el que planteas. Por lo general lo he visto principalmente en la creación de frameworks.

No digo que no continues con lo que deseas sino que trata de repensar que el hacerlo será forzar un asunto sencillo a algo muy general, poderoso y abstracto.

Las librerías que necesitarías para realizar metaprogramación serían `ast` con sus funciones como `parse`, `inspect` y otras como `astunparse`, etc. Entonces podrás analizar un código fuente de python, leerlo, editarlo y volverlo a poner en su lugar estando modificado. Eso es poderosísimo pero conlleva muchas responsabilidades, sobretodo el que sea interesante lo que haces y que tengas cuidado con el orden de tu paquete.

Por otro lado, si quieres resolver ese problema con un lugar externo al programa de donde obtengas las monedas y los tipos de cambio, trata de utilizar un manejo de bases de datos, ya sea con `mysql`, `sqlite`, `mongodb`, etc o un simple archivo de texto externo con un formato que especifiques, y de ahí obtienes lo que necesitas con los conectores o herramientas adecuadas a cada caso.

Incluso puedes utilizar la conexión a alguna API que haga las conversiones desde una petición http.

Para tu programa, te podrías ayudar de [este](https://gitlab.com/mrc_es/conversor/blob/master/conversor.py) código que hice,
cuya ejecución, que requiere de Python3+, resultaría semejante a esto.

```
Elige una moneda a convertir disponible:
* euro
* sol
* real
* peso uruguayo
* peso chileno
> euro
Elige un tipo de cambio disponible:
* sol
* real
* peso uruguayo
* peso chileno
> sol
Elige la cantidad a convertir:
> 4
La conversion de 4 unidades de euro a sol es:
4.4
Elige una moneda a convertir disponible:
* euro
* sol
* real
* peso uruguayo
* peso chileno
```

Que aunque incompleto por el manejo de excepciones y otras cosas, te puede servir para realizar las tareas básicas que deseas. Nada más tendrías que ajustar al tipo de cambio que desees y, si quieres agregar otro, añadirlo al diccionario de conversiones.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de hacer lo que quieres es creando un archivo externo con la configuración de las conversiones y llamándolas desde el archivo python.
Si bien, no necesariamente las conversiones de moneda tienen una única referencia, para cuestiones **didácticas e ilustrativas** voy a referenciar todas las monedas al dolar. Siendo así, entonces la conversión es sencilla: `(equiv2/equiv1)*cantidad`.

Nota: Este código no tiene captura de errores o prevención de desbordamiento de índice (si pones 7 por ejemplo, da error). Es algo que ya debes hacer antes de "*ponerlo en producción*"

El archivo de configuración, es un texto plano que contiene un json con los datos, aunque puedes usar otro formato que no sea json (ini, lista, etc).

> monedas.json

```
{
"1": ["Dolares", 1], 
"2": ["Euros", 0.89], 
"3": ["Soles", 3.32], 
"4": ["Reales", 3.92], 
"5": ["Pesos uruguayos", 33.81], 
"6": ["Pesos Chilenos", 680.5]
}
```

El py toma esos valores, los convierte a un diccionario y arma el menú con esos datos.

```
import json

def convertir_moneda():
    with open("monedas.json") as json_file:
        xdata = json.load(json_file) # Se convierte en dict

    for num_opt, valor in xdata.items():
        print('{} - {}'.format(num_opt, valor[0]))

    print()
    x = input("Escoge tu moneda original: ")
    y = input("Escoge tu moneda convertida: ")
    cant = float(input("Cantidad a convertir: "))

    # Suponiendo que todas las monedas tomaran como referencia el dollar
    nuevo_valor = (xdata[y][1] / xdata[x][1]) * cant

    print()
    print("{} {} equivalen a {:.4f} {}".format(cant, xdata[x][0], nuevo_valor, xdata[y][0]))

convertir_moneda()
```

Una salida de ejemplo

```
1 - Dolares
2 - Euros
3 - Soles
4 - Reales
5 - Pesos uruguayos
6 - Pesos Chilenos

Escoge tu moneda original: 1
Escoge tu moneda convertida: 3
Cantidad a convertir: 28

28.0 Dolares equivalen a 92.9600 Soles
```